# How to come back our application page after pressing cancel button in email?

Tags: android

How can I comeback from e-mail application to my application when I pressed the cancel button in e-mail application.

This is my code which is used to send an e-mail:

```
Intent intentEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"your.email@gmail.com"});
intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "your subject");
intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message body");
intentEmail.setType("message/rfc822");
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentEmail, "Choose an email provider :"));
```

Comment: Have you call `finish()` on button click?

Comment: i need to come back my application when cancel button in email app pressed

Comment: I guess it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is not possible.If you press the **back button of the device**,then control will come back to your app(**if finished is not called**).

But you cannot handle behaviour of the button click in the email app.Hence it is not possible.

Comment: then it is any possibility to load email in our own app?

Comment: for that you have to use some api of the email client you are using

Answer (score 0):

try this 
paste this code in your mail page

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// pass intent to you activity here
}
```